# return true in php and obtain result in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ionic-framework

I have a javascript function that I want to redirect to php on my server obtain a result and then if that php file returns true to complete the function. I've tried this:

```
if (window.location.href = "http://cosy.azurewebsites.net/servertest.php?u=" + Username + "&p=" + Password ==true)
    {
       alert ("it was true");

    }
```

But that just returns false no matter what I do.

When I go to the php page here is where I return null and go back to the javascript:

```
header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)?result=true/false");
            return true;

            //header('Location:some_page.php?result=true/false');
            exit;
```

I know it isn't the right way to do it but I tried a few different things and this is as far as I get!!

Comment: I think what you need is a [jQuery ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: I do not understand what you need, can you edit the question to clarify. Maybe @AuditeMarlow can do it.

Comment: make ajax call to http://cosy.azurewebsites.net/servertest.php?u=" + Username + "&p=" + Password and send true or false response from server

Comment: your making an assignment instead of comparing

Comment: `window.location.href == "http://cosy.azurewebsites.net/servertest.php?u=" + Username + "&p=" + Password )`

Comment: also don't put a password in your #href thats horrible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from what I can tell you want to fire off a request using Javascript to your Server, then want PHP to react to that request and return true, and then your JS file should react to the response.

What you are going to need to use is AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript And XML) request. The easiest method would be to use JQuery, it also means that they can handle cross-browser comparability for you.

You can find the official docs here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

I'll provide a quick example, but I think you'll learn more by experimenting with it yourself.

**JS File:**

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    url: 'end-point.com/servertest.php?u=' + Username,
    dataType: 'json',    
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.result === true) {
            // Run your function.
        }
    }    
});
```

**PHP File:**

```
<?php

// Do whatever check you are doing, for the example i'll just return true.
echo json_encode([result => true]);
```

I'd advise researching into AJAX it s a very handy tool.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted thanks I will look into it. When I call this in my javascript it is giving me Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined is there an import I need to do for ajax?

Comment: Ah yeah, JQuery is an external library, you can download it and store it yourself or you can just use google's hosted library to include the library by using the following `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` and just so you know this is sourced from here: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery :)

Comment: That worked just need to figure out the HTTP access control (CORS) part now but cheers

Answer (score 1):

First off, I think what you need is a [jQuery ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), although it's really vague what you actually want to achieve with your current description.

Second off, you're trying to retrieve a `return` value from a page which essentially only redirects to another page.

What you can do, is run an ajax call to your PHP script, and do something according to the return value that's given back from the script to JS. For example:

In your servertest.php:

```
<?php
    ...

    die(json_encode(true));
?>
```

In your JS script:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'path/to/servertest.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        u: Username,
        p: Password
    },
    success: function (data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);

        if (data === true) {
            alert('it was true');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted thanks I will look into it. When I call this in my javascript it is giving me Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined is there an import I need to do for ajax?

Comment: You will need to include the jQuery library before you will be able to use any jQuery. Include the following in your website `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>` and have a look at the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/).